# The meaning of hyperparameters in glove

Tags: nlp, hyperparameters, glove

The following is hyperparameters in [demo.sh of glove](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/blob/master/demo.sh). What is the meaning of `VERBOSE`, `MEMORY`, `WINDOW_SIZE` and `BINARY`.

The `WINDOW_SIZE` is 15, is that means chose 15 words from right and chose 15 words from left?

```
VERBOSE=2        ?
MEMORY=4.0       ?
VOCAB_MIN_COUNT=5
VECTOR_SIZE=128
MAX_ITER=15
WINDOW_SIZE=15   ?
BINARY=2         ?
NUM_THREADS=8
X_MAX=100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VERBOSE` is a regular parameter for model training nowadays, its value tells the function how much information to print while training the model. Usually `0` means no intermediate information, `1` means minimal and `2` means a lot more detail. (check: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/blob/master/src/cooccur.c) for more details about what are printed.

`MEMORY`: I'm not quite sure about this but I think it has to do with the memory usage for the model training. (feel free to correct & update)

`WINDOW_SIZE`: yes, it's the context size (check: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/blob/master/src/cooccur.c)

`BINARY`: It's a switch option for file output type. `0` for text file, `1` for binary, and `2` for both (check: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/blob/master/src/glove.c).